# cannot convert blob to string, SQLite+java

Tags: java, sqlite

I used following code for retrieve data from SQLite database. The 4th column of database stored string as BLOB. Now i need to get that string values back. But `Blob blob = exe.getBlob("col_4");` gave me an exception `not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver`. How can i solve this ?

```
Connection c = null;
Statement stm = null;

String db = "C:\\Users\\Asus™\\Desktop\\New folder (2)\\tempo.db";
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + db);
    c.setAutoCommit(false);

    System.out.println("DB opened successfully !");

    stm = c.createStatement();
    int rc = 0;
    try (ResultSet exe = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblTest;")) {
        while (exe.next()) {
            Blob blob = exe.getBlob("col_4");
            String password = new String(blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length()));

            System.out.println(password
                    + exe.getString("col_1") + "\t"
                    + exe.getString("col_2") + "\t"
                    + exe.getString("col_3") + "\t"
                    + password
            );
            rc++;
        }
        System.out.println(rc++);
    }
    stm.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SQLiteBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SQLiteBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

}

Exception :

```
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
       at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.unused(JDBC4ResultSet.java:320)
       at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.getBlob(JDBC4ResultSet.java:345)
       at sqlite.SQLiteBrowser.jButton1ActionPerformed(SQLiteBrowser.java:256)
       at sqlite.SQLiteBrowser.access$000(SQLiteBrowser.java:29)
       at sqlite.SQLiteBrowser$1.actionPerformed(SQLiteBrowser.java:76)
       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
```

Comment: Why do you think that the password field is not encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that `ResultSet#getBlob` method is not supported by this JDBC library implementation (due to [sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.8.5-pre1/org/sqlite/jdbc4/JDBC4ResultSet.java#JDBC4ResultSet.getBlob%28int%29), JDBC4ResultSet doesn't implement it). You may try to use `ResultSet#getBytes` instead:

```
byte[] bytes = exe.getBytes("col_4");
String password = new String(bytes);
```

Comment: `String password = new String(bytes);` returns unrecognized characters. Such as `Ќ����z`.

Comment: you can try to create a blob back and try to transform it into the string Blob blob = c.createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, bytes); but not sure it helps, try to check encoding may be

Answer (score 0):

`getBlob()` method is not supportedby SQLite ... but blobs are supported ... you need to use `getBytes` :

```
byte[] bytes = exe.getBytes("col_4");
```

Comment: how can i get bytes as `String` in correct format (not unrecognized characters, `Ќ����z. – `) ?

Comment: someting like `String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8" );` ... or using apache commons library : `String str = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8" );`